# Own fast Gamma Index implementation

Tags: algorithm, performance, image-processing, concurrency, scientific-computing

My friends and I are writing our own implementation of Gamma Index algorithm. It should compute it within 1s for standard size 2d pictures (512 x 512) though could also calculate 3D pictures; be portable and easy to install and maintain.

Gamma Index, in case if you haven't came across this topic, is a method for comparing pictures. On input we provide two pictures (reference and target); every picture consist of points distributed over regular fine grid; every point has location and value. As output we receive a picture of Gamma Index values. For each point of target picture we calculate some function (called gamma) against every point from reference picture (in original version) or against points from reference picture, that are closest to the one from target picture (in version, that is usually used in Gamma Index calculation software). The Gamma Index for certain target point is minimum of calculated for it gamma function.

So far we have tried following ideas with these results:

- use GPU - the calculation time has decreased 10 times. Problem is, that it's fairly difficult to install it on machines with non nVidia graphics card
- use supercomputer or cluster - the problem is with maintenance of this solution. Plus every picture has to be ciphered for travel through network due to data sensitivity
- iterate points ordered by their distances to target point with some extra stop criterion - this way we got 15 seconds at best condition (which is actually not ideally precise)
- currently we are writing in Python due to NumPy awesome optimizations over matrix calculation, but we are open for other languages too.

Do you have any ideas how we can accelerate our algorithm(s), in order to meet the objectives? Do you think the obtaining of this level of performance is possible?

Some more information about GI for anyone interested: 
http://lcr.uerj.br/Manual_ABFM/A%20technique%20for%20the%20quantitative%20evaluation%20of%20dose%20distributions.pdf

Comment: You can use OpenCL for GPU-implementations on non-nVidia cards.

Comment: Thanks for getting interested in topic and our problem. Wr have already tried running this on OpenCL. The problem with the solution is, that it should be available for major architectures and installing OpenCL library on older graphics cards is quite painfull though.